# Scroll Moves to top when I push data to the top of the ngrepeat which is ordered on basis of dat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scroll, scrollbar, push

In angular js, I have used `ng-repeat` for the messages appearing top to bottom.

In the bottom, the latest will be there. Old messages will appear when I will scroll up, On scroll reaches the top, API is hit and more old data is pushed to the top of the list.

Now, whenever, new data loaded, scroller moves to the top of the screen and when I pull it down by calculating the height of new data added, it shows on screen (**Shake screen from top to the same position in nanoseconds which looks very bad**)

Comment: please share the code

Comment: its a big project....so i cannot share fragmented code here

Answer (score 0):

You're using some directive to wrapper up this behavior? If you're using, you could test the preventDefault() method (presuming that you're using jquery) to avoid page scroll up. If you're not using directives you should consider use to have a better control under this kind of behaviors.

Comment: preventdefault didn't worked for me. Actually, as soon the new content is added, scroller stick to top. Not using any directive, on window scroll reaches top, I hit api for older messages

Comment: Could you share a sample of this code for me or another guy try help you? Don't need be whole code, only this sample.